# conditional constraint in optimization

Tags: if-statement, optimization, constraints, conditional-statements, linear-programming

Does anybody know how to write conditional constraint in mixed integer programming for this case:

```
if a == 0 then b = 1
else b = 0
-M <= a <= M
b={0,1}
```

Note that M can be any continuous number.
Thanks.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this as follows. First use a variable splitting approach by introducing two non-negative variables `aplus, amin`:

```
0 <= aplus <= d*M
0 <= amin <= (1-d)*M
a = aplus-amin
d in {0,1}
```

Now we can do:

```
0.001*(1-b) <= aplus + amin <= M*(1-b)
```

In many cases we can simplify this but that requires knowledge of the rest of the model.

Comment: It worked! Just a small correction for the last equation: 0.001*(1-b) <= aplus + amin <= M*(1-b)  should be 0.001*(1-b) <= aplus + amin <= M*b

Comment: I think my version is correct. If `b=1` then `0<=aplus+amin<=0 ==> aplus+amin=0`. If `b=0` then `0.01 <= aplus+amin <= M`.