# Scipy Optimization: Conditional Constrains (two intervals for 1 variable)

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, scipy, constraints, minimization

I came across: [conditional constraint in optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764680/conditional-constraint-in-optimization)

It was close, but not clear enough for me to translate to my specific use case.

What I need (constraint wise):

```
if x < M:
    then x = 0
    else x = x
```

another way to put it:

```
X = {x: x=0 or x>M}
```

I want to set a minimum x but for the optimization algorithm to still be able to consider a value of x=0.

Here's the code:

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.array(____constraint - est___(x))},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.array(main.max____ / 100 - (x))},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.array((x) - 5)})

x0 = np.zeros(len(master____optimization_table))

res = minimize(___model, x0, constraints=cons, options=opts)
```

*The functions calculate important metrics we are constraining. The only one I need help with is the third line of constraints.

This seems extremely useful, if it is possible that is.

Comment: What is shown in that link is not possible in scipy. There is no optimizer supporting *mixed-integer* programming.

Comment: You could solve the problem twice, once with x=0 and once with the constraint x > M, and then pick the best solution.  If you have several variables (say, `n` variables) that you want to handle this way, you would have to solve the problem `2^n` times, so this method probably isn't feasible if `n` is too big.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser That ended up being my temporary solution. Add a binary column to multiply by in the ____model. First optimize with x>0, if x<M, set that binary to zero, reoptimize with x > M, and optimization won't even have to deal with the < M terms because they will be multiplied by 0.